# SetwindowsHookEX not working when run app in admin mode

Tags: windows, winforms, setwindowshookex

I have native dll for setting the windows hook (global) and i am calling it in one of my windows form application to set a global hook. It works perfectly fine and i get the messages in the app.

But when i run my windows form app in admin mode then i don't get any messages from the windows hook. Any help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is explained for [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx): *"The usual security boundaries apply"*. Do you have a question?